# C# NestedClass Expanded Property to Refresh/Invalidate Control in Design Mode

Tags: c#, winforms, inner-classes, invalidation, nested-properties

I'm trying to reproduce how Font class Nested Property is able to `Invalidate()` it's containing Control when the values are changed from the Properties window, without a need to lost focus on the form window.
Like if you change the Size property, the Form window will be automatically redrawn with a matching Font Size.

The complete code is at the end of this post

1. The test `NestedClass` is very simple which has two Properties and uses a custom `ExpandableObjectConverter`.
2. The `ContainerClass` extends Control class. It invokes `Control.Invalidate()` method when the `NestedClass` value is changed. Properties of the `NestedClass` are drawn by overriding `Control.OnPaint()` method.

Resulting Control when loaded to the Designer : [Initial Draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irWt2.jpg)

Changing the values directly from the `NestedClass` parent property triggers the redraw : [Updating from the parent property works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTlmG.jpg)

But changing the values from the nested property, does not redraw : [Updating from the nested properties doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpJ5Q.jpg)

If later the Form window is clicked, `Invalidate()` is triggered : [After Form window clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dJJm.jpg)

Font class does not require extra click in the design window in order to redraw the control. Can we achieve this same behavior with a custom class like this?

For reference I've already looked into :

1. `INotifyPropertyChanged` ==> Problem here is that the PropertyChanged event is only subscribed by the container Control when the item is first added. If I close the Form[Design] window and reopens it, the event will not be subscribed again.
2. `RefreshProperties.All` or `RefreshProperties.Repaint` does not seems to do anything.

If all else fails, obviously clicking on the form designer window will solve the problem, but it bugs me that a built-in .NET class can do this, but a custom class cannot. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

The Code :

```
//The Nested Class
[TypeConverter(typeof(NestedClassTypeConverter))]
public class NestedClass
{
    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public string CountryName { get; set; } = "Japan";

    [NotifyParentProperty(true)]
    public string Capital { get; set; } = "Tokyo";

}

//The Container Class
public class ContainerClass : Control
{
    private NestedClass _country = new NestedClass();
    [Category("_Data")]
    public NestedClass Country
    {
        get => _country;
        set
        {
            _country = value;
            this.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    protected override Size DefaultSize => new Size(100, 100);
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);
        using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Country.CountryName, this.Font, b, new PointF(10, 10));
            e.Graphics.DrawString(Country.Capital, this.Font, b, new PointF(10, 50));
        }
    }

}

//TypeConverter for that fancy Expandable properties
public class NestedClassTypeConverter : ExpandableObjectConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        if (sourceType == typeof(string))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }

    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            string[] v = ((string)value).Split(',');
            return new NestedClass
            {
                CountryName = v[0],
                Capital = v[1]
            };
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }

    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(NestedClass))
        {
            return true;
        }
        return base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }

    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return ((NestedClass)value).CountryName + "," + ((NestedClass)value).Capital;
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't put "solved" in the title.  Just accept your answer to complete the post.

Comment: @LarsTech noted. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny that after a day of searching without any luck, and finally posted my question, suddenly I found another thread which speaks the very same issue with answer --> [Thread with the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37015016/c-sharp-custom-control-redraw-after-changing-a-member-objects-properties)

Just to reiterate, apparently `INotifyPropertyChanged` is still the answer to my problem. The difference is that I was subscribing to the event on the `ContainerClass` constructor before. Something like :

```
public ContainerClass()
{
    NestedClassInstance.PropertyChanged += delegate { this.Invalidate(); };
}
```

While apparently what needs to done is to subscribe or resubscribe to that event on the `NestedClass` setter body. Something like :

```
public class ContainerClass : Control
{
    private NestedClass _nestedClassInstance = new NestedClassInstance();
    public NestedClass NestedClassInstance
    {
        get => _nestedClassInstance;
        set
        {
            if (_nestedClassInstance != null)
                _nestedClassInstance.PropertyChanged -= delegate { this.Invalidate(); };
            _nestedClassInstance = value;
            _nestedClassINstance.PropertyChanged += delegate { this.Invalidate(); };
        }
    }
}
```

There you have it. End of another coding journey.

**EDIT :**
Actually I'm still thinking whether this is the actual solution or not, since if we're referring to Font class metadata, it does not necessarily uses `INotifyProperty` or any other sort of EventHandler for a property changed event. But anyway, this does the trick.